# Java Web Start doesn't work after version 7u25

Tags: java, security, java-web-start

I have a java application that is launchend via java web start (with glassfish 4.0). After updating to java 7u25, it doesn't work anymore. Here is a part of the error message.

```
Missing Permissions manifest attribute for: http://localhost:8080/___JWSappclient/___system/s1as/glassfish/modules/javax.security.auth.message-api.jar
Missing Codebase manifest attribute for: http://localhost:8080/___JWSappclient/___system/s1as/glassfish/modules/javax.security.auth.message-api.jar
Missing Permissions manifest attribute for: http://localhost:8080/___JWSappclient/___system/s1as/glassfish/modules/web-naming.jar
Missing Codebase manifest attribute for: http://localhost:8080/___JWSappclient/___system/s1as/glassfish/modules/web-naming.jar
#### Java Web Start Error:
#### java.lang.ClassCircularityError: com/sun/enterprise/security/ee/PermissionCache
Exception in thread "Javaws Secure Thread" java.lang.ClassCircularityError: com/sun/enterprise/security/ee/PermissionCache
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.isCheckMemberAccessOverridden(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.checkMemberAccess(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.getURLStreamHandler(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
```

First of all, why is there suddenly a ClassCircularityError? Furthermore, to elminiate the attribute warnings, I might add the attributes to the manifest. But it is really a good plan to modify third-party jars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have noticed this problem as well and are tracking it via this just-opened GlassFish [issue 20711](https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-20711).

Answer (score 1):

Adding the `Permissions` and `Codebase` attribute in the manifest.mf file of the jar might resolve your problem. These are the latest updates in [update 25](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/7u25-relnotes-1955741.html). For your second question regarding the prompts, Change in third party jars is not appreciable. I'm myself stuck with this removal of prompts.

Comment: I added the attributes to the manifest.mf of the top-level jar, but still the same warnings/exception (even for the top-level jar). As you can see in the error message, there are glassfish 4 jars with missing attributes. I am not sure if I really should change GF jars

Comment: There are only 2 jars missing those attributes. For the new prompt of mixedcode there is the attribute `Trusted-Library` which Oracle introduced in their [Java 7 update 21](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/7u21-relnotes-1932873.html). As i told you , me too is stuck with the warning, but adding the attributes to manifest of third party jars resolves the problem. You can raise a bug on Oracle for the same, but before that do check by adding the appropriate attributes.

Comment: I only posted a small part of the error log here. In fact, there are about 40-50 glassfish jars that generate a Missing Manifest Attribute warning. I don't think I should change so many GF jars?

Comment: Ohh, i agree, its not advisable to edit so many jars. but you can change their attributes and be sure about the problem. Else raise a case on Oracle.